# Can't change BG color of div if it has a certain img title

Tags: css, jss

I'm trying to highlight a patent div if a nested, child div contains an image with a specific title.

I've semi-successfully used class selector, but it only adds a border around the image vs changing the bg color of the parent/container div.

What specifically do I need to put in my css to accomplish my goal?

Class selector code:

```css
[title~="THIS"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="mom">
    <b class="titlecenter">mom title</b>
  </div>

  <div class="pics">
    <a href="link.html">
      <p class="center"><img src="img.gif" title="yup!"></p>
    </a>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Class selector code used above

Comment: This ... `[title~="THIS"]` ... is not a class selector.  It is an *attribute* selector.

Comment: If you want to set background color, then why don't you?  The rule presented in the question does not specify a value for the `background-color` property, so of course it does not affect background colors.

Comment: However, the CSS specs do not offer selectors that discriminate based on the properties of descendant elements.  Some implementations provide a `:has()` pseudoclass that serves exactly that purpose, but it is not standard (yet) nor universal.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to learn the proper terms. 

I did not include the code for bg color because I understand how that works. I'm trying to find how to reference the div where the image may be to see if the parent div bg needs to be changed. 

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:has` selector which is supported by all major browsers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

```css
.pics:has(img[title~="yup!"]) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="pics">
                <a href="link.html">
            <p class="center"><img src="img.gif" title="yup!"></p>
        </a>    
    </div>
    
        <div class="pics">
                <a href="link.html">
            <p class="center"><img src="img.gif" title="nope!"></p>
        </a>    
    </div>
```

Comment: Important distinction: `:has()` is supported by *new enough versions* of all major browsers.  The one I happen to be using right now is relatively recent, but not recent enough.  Relying on `:has()` is still a bit dicey at this point.

Comment: It's true that `:has()` is not supported in all browsers, however, it's supported in all **major** browsers. i.e. Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge and Opera. for mobiles, it's supported in Chrome, Safari and Samsung internet. that's said, I think it's fair enough to use it unless you really need support for every single browser that exists, don't you agree? @JohnBollinger

Comment: Check browser support: https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas

Comment: @MHDAlaaAlhaj, I made no objection to the "major browsers" part.  Again, it's *new enough versions* that is the issue.  The browser I am using right now that does not support `:has()` is Firefox 102.  On my system, right now, I could readily upgrade as far as Firefox 115, which is still not [new enough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility).  `:has()` is an up and coming feature, but there is still a significant fraction of real people for whom it will not work.